# Gatsby GraphQL issue

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I am rather new to Gatsby. I am using Strapi as backend and in my frontend Gatsby, in the GraphQL playground I am executing the following query with expected outcome:

```
query MyQuery {
  strapiAssessment {
    title
    rating {
      id
      topic
      rate
    }
  }
}
```

In my Gatsby frontend code I have the following:

```
import React from "react"
import Title from "../components/Title"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

const SelfAssesment = ({ data }) => {
  const {
    strapiAssessment: { title, rating },
  } = data
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <section className="section jobs">
      <Title title={title} />
      <div className="about-stack">
        <p>Rankning i olika teknologier:</p>
        {rating.map(item => {
          return <span key={item.id}>{item.topic}</span>
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="about-stack">
        {rating.map(item => {
          return <span key={item.id}>{item.rate}</span>
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  {
    strapiAssessment {
      title
      rating {
        id
        topic
        rate
      }
    }
  }
`

export default SelfAssesment
```

I am getting the following error:

[image]

I am getting undefined, do I have something undeclared or a typo somewhere?

Comment: What's the prompt of the `console.log(data)` (if you place it before the destructuring)

Comment: It shows up as undefined on the line where I put it as your suggestion before destructuring

Comment: Is this a page component or a partial (child) component you import into the main page component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a page query in a component that is not in a top-level (`components/SelfAssesment`). As you can see from the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/recipes/querying-data/):

> **Querying data with a Page Query**
>
> You can use the `graphql` tag to query data in the pages of your Gatsby
> site. This gives you access to anything included in Gatsby’s data
> layer, such as site metadata, source plugins, images, and more.
>
> **Querying data with the StaticQuery Component**
>
> `StaticQuery` is a component for retrieving data from Gatsby’s data
> layer in [non-page components](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/), such as a header, navigation, or any
> other child component.

That said, you have two options here. Use the query in a top-level component (page) and drill-down the `props` down to the component or use a `StaticQuery` (or `useStaticQuery` hook).